# When passing a 2d array as parameter with pointers to print its values it only prints zero

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-call, pointer-arithmetic

So, i have to make a function that takes a 2d array as parameter with a pointer, specifically, so that cant be changed.

This function that i wrote works, but when i print it, it only prints zeros. When printing directly in main() it works normally.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
void calcula_media(float (*matriz)[3]){

    int i, j;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            *(*(matriz+i)+j)=i+j;
            printf("%.1f ", (*(matriz+i)+j));
        }
    }
    
}

void main(){

    float matriz[3][3]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int i, j;
    
    calcula_media(matriz[3]);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%.1f ", *(*(matriz+i)+j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function argument is not an array of pointers, it's an array of arrays.

Comment: You're also not passing the whole array to the function. `matriz[3]` is a single row of the matrix. And it's out of bounds, since the highest index is `matriz[2]`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I meant that in `main()` it's an array of arrays.

Comment: matriz[3] is the 4th row of matriz (which has 3 rows)

Comment: Which part of the code are you not allowed to change?

Comment: The argument to `calcula_media` should me `matriz`, not `matrix[3]`. Your initialization of `matriz` is also broken, btw. And you may wanna ask yourself why, in `calcula_media`, you're using `printf("%.1f ", (*(matriz+i)+j));`, but in `main` you're using an additional level of indirection.

Comment: @Barmar removing the [3] and adding the * fixed it, such silly mistakes! Anyway, thanks so much for your help

Comment: please replace `*(*(matriz+i)+j)` with `matriz[i][j]`

Comment: In `void calcula_media(float (*matriz)[3])`, `matriz` is not a 2-d array.    It is a pointer to an array of floats.  In C, you cannot pass arrays to functions.  (You can pass a struct that contains an array, however.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument expression in this call

```
calcula_media(matriz[3]);
```

is incorrect. It has the type `float *` (and moreover the pointer expression points outside the array `matriz`) while the function expects an argument of the type `float (*matriz)[3]`

```
void calcula_media(float (*matriz)[3]){
```

Call the function like

```
calcula_media(matriz);
```

In this case the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `float[3]`.

And in this call of printf

```
printf("%.1f ", (*(matriz+i)+j));
```

you need to dereference the pointer expression

```
printf("%.1f ", *(*(matriz+i)+j));
```

Comment: thanks! i also had forgotten a * in the printf, but changing those two things made it work!